# How to use the DXGI flip model in a Direct2D windowed app?

Tags: winapi, direct2d, dxgi

I have a Win32 non-game windowed app that uses a Direct2D device context/HWND render target to draw a window. Currently it uses a DXGI swap chain with the `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` swap effect.

[Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/for-best-performance--use-dxgi-flip-model) using the new flip model swap effects, either `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD`. I'm interested in using them primarily because they would allow me to specify a list of dirty rects when calling `Present1()`, which should improve performance/power usage.

Simply changing the `SwapEffect` to either of the new flip model values produces a weird (but actually expected) result of drawing a black window each second frame, with artifacts of the previous frames visible onscreen.

So the question is: **is it possible to use the new flip model swap effects in this situation, and if yes, how should things be set up**?

Given that the app needs to draw the dirty rects into an otherwise valid buffer, it seems that a correct approach would involve maintaining two buffers with essentially the same content (one to draw into, and one to give to the DWM for composition), so not sure if it would be possible to achieve any performance gains this way in an app that doesn't redraw each frame completely. But perhaps I'm missing something important.

The swap chain is currently set up as follows:

```
swapChainDesc.Width = ...;
swapChainDesc.Height = ...;
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
```

**EDIT 1**

It turns out that `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` forces `BufferCount` to 1, so my initial value of 2 was somewhat misleading, as only one buffer is used. [Source (3rd comment).](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/679050-how-come-changing-dxgi-swap-chain-descbuffercount-has-no-effect/)

Also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ne-dxgi-dxgi_swap_effect) for `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT` say that UWP apps are forced into the flip model, so this should be a solvable problem.

Comment: Could you talk more about how you do rendering? Do you not draw the whole screen every frame? DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD will make the contents of back buffer undefined at the start of the frame - are you relying on it keeping pixels from the previous frame?

Comment: @Sunius The rendering is done with `Begin/EndDraw()` and a `Present1()` afterwards. In between the `Begin/EndDraw()` I redraw the dirty rects only (when possible). Note that this is a windowed app (think Notepad), not a fullscreen one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good ways to do it.

The first way is a little heavier on energy usage. You can draw your contents into an intermediate buffer/render texture, and copy it to swapchain just before every present. That way you can only actually render the parts that changed in your intermediate buffer, and not care about what the state of the swapchain is.

The second way is more complicated, but can yield optimal energy usage. Instead of using intermediate buffer and drawing only what changes since the last frame there, you draw directly into the swapchain buffer. For this to work correctly, you need to redraw not what changes between current and last frame, but between current and (current - BufferCount) frame. For instance:

Frame 1 - you draw a green rectancle at (200 x 200) with dimensions of (150 x 150). The dirty region is entire frame because it's the first frame.

Frame 2 - you draw a blue rectangle at (250 x 250) with dimensions of (50 x 50). The dirty region is (250, 250, 300, 300).

Frame 3 - you draw a red rectangle at (225 x 225) with dimensions of (50 x 50). The dirty region is (225, 225, 50, 50).

If your buffer count is 2, that means when you draw frame 3, you need to not only redraw the dirty region of (225, 225, 50, 50), but also the dirty region of (250, 250, 300, 300).

Comment: The #2 is genius in its simplicity. Thank you.